# On View Rewrite Results I don't see additional options like Add Read More button when checked "Trim this field to a maximum length"

Tags: views

Can anyone help me? Because earlier this options were displayed when I checked "Trim this field to a maximum length". May be it depends on some settings?

I can't upload image to show you what I mean. But try to explain. 
I have a view block which displays some articles of the content type. I have some fields of content type to display. One of them is Body. I want to trim it because it can be very long and set "View more" link to the current article. I choose "Trim this field to a maximum length" in the "Rewrite Rules" of the field but nothing happens, additional options aren't shown to me, so I can't set number of characters to display, title of "View more" link, path and etc.

Comment: plz expande details

Answer (score 0):

My guess it is a Jquery incompatabilty. I had the same problem this morning while setting up a new site. After activating views there where no accordions and a faulty overlay.

So i set the Jquery-version in Jquery-Update Module from 1.8 to 1.5 and everything turned back to normal.

Edit: here's the issue queue on drupal.org: http://drupal.org/node/1869988

Comment: Thanks! Your are right. The problem was in jQuery. I had version 1.7. When I changed jQuery to 1.5 it fixed the problem.